# How do you access an object's (ActiveRecord::Relation) value by key in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

tl;dr How do I get the corresponding value with the key of an object?

I'm confused why

`Atag.where(tag:'brand')` gives me what I would call an object for lack of a better term: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Atag id: 1, tag: "brand", created_at: "2015-01-31 04:29:20", updated_at: "2015-01-31 04:29:20">]>`

But I'm having the basic difficult of accessing the corresponding value for the key :id.

`Atag.where(tag:'brand').id` and `Atag.where(tag:'brand')[:id]` and `Atag.where(tag:'brand')(:id)` all throw errors, while in this case I'm just trying to have the integer 1 returned.

I seem to be unable to ruby, nor find a succinct answer to this basic question with my google searching skills (or lack there of).

Thanks

Comment: ah did Atag.where(tag:'brand')[0].id and that worked

Comment: I see the 'where' method returned an object of objects, so I needed to specify I wanted the first object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the id of your tag = 'brand' with following query:

```
Atag.find_by(tag:'brand').id
```

Check following variations:

```
Atag.find(1) 
#gives you the object with the Atag id = 1

Atag.find(100) #let's say this record does not exist then you will 
get ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception.
```

**Better option :**

```
Atag.where(id: 1) 
#this returns you a relation and it's true you are trying to access
 only a single object.

Hence, you just need to modify it to :
Atag.where(id: 1).first 
#Above one will give you an object of Atag not an association result.
# to verfiy you can execute, Atag.where(id: 1).first.class

Atag.where(id: 999).first
 # In this case if there is no record found with id = 999, then it'll 
return  nil which can be easily handled than an exception found 
while using find method.
```

Get the same flavor using the dynamic finders.

```
Atag.find_by(id: 1) #gives the Atag with id 1 
Atag.find_by_id(1). # same as above.
Atag.find_by(id: 999) #if not found then simply returns nil. 
Atag.find_by(name: 'ruby') #return Atag object with name: 'ruby'
Atag.find_by_name('ruby') #same as above.
```

Comment: This is useful, but a different from what I was looking for, as I needed to be able to retrieve the value with knowledge only of the key. Your examples seem to assume knowledge of the key and value to retrieve the object. The reason I am retrieving the objects by :tag instead of :id is because I have the value of :tag but not the :id (which is what I am trying to get). There is almost definitely a better way to implement what I'm trying to with Active Record Associations, but I'm just working on a implementation from scratch for now while I get more comfortable and inspired by making progress.

Comment: I'm not big on reading docs, except the bare minimum, but at some point in the near future I'll thoroughly go through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html if I get too stuck :P

Comment: @Laser, are you trying to get all the Atag objects having a common tag name ? Just like you did Atag.where(tag: 'brand') ? then you can try Atag.find_by(tag: 'brand')

Comment: Ah yes that's much cleaner! Thanks :)

Comment: Can you edit the answer so that the solution is at the top 'Atag.find_by(tag:'brand').id' or 'Atag.where(tag:'brand').first.id'?

Comment: Great, thanks :) Hopefully it'll be of use to someone at some point

Answer (score 7):

From great documentation at the [Odin Project](http://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/active-record-queries).

> The key thing to note is that `#find` returns the actual record while `#where` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which basically acts like an array.
>
> So if you're using `#where` to find a single record, you still need to remember to go into that "array" and grab the first record, e.g. `User.where(:email => "foo@bar.com")[0]` or `User.where(:email => "foo@bar.com").first.`

This gets me all the time...

Comment: I'd like to add: it's possible to chain `.id` onto things. So for @Laser original question, a possible solution would be: `Atag.select(:id).limit(1).first.id` What this is doing is collecting the ActiveRecord::Relation object (which is essentially an Array) looking at the first element, and specifically the id of the first element. This way it's not necessary to ever know the actual id before referencing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, looks like you figured it out. For reference, you can use `Atag.where(tag:'brand').first` to get the first result, and `Atag.where(tag:'brand').to_a` to get an array of all the matching results.

Answer (score 1):

> `where` return instance of *ActiveRecord::Relation* which can be treated like an **array** with records as its members. Even if the result is single it should be accessed like a member of array with single element

```
Atag.where(tag: 'brand')
```

returns the array of results and to access `id` we should **get the record from the array first** i.e.

```
Atag.where(tag: 'brand')[0].id
```

In order to get `id` of all the matching records we need to use [pluck](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) with `where`. `pluck` returns an array of attribute that is plucked.

```
Atag.where(tag: 'brand').pluck(:id)
```

This would return an array of `id` from the collection returned by `where` only.

> The `find_by` method finds the first record matching some conditions. Since `find_by` returns the record (**not an array**) , we can do:

```
Atag.find_by(tag: 'brand').id
```

**PS:** No one had mentioned `pluck` that's why I wrote this answer. Hope its helpful.